# when jackson auto detect setter, can I force it to use the pascal case?

Tags: java, jackson

Currently when jackson object mapper auto detetc setter, it defaults to lower case. Can I change the mapping to Pascal case?

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to create custom AnnotationIntrospector that can find setters/getters that use different naming convention. But there is no automatic way to define mapping between external (in JSON) names to bean properties, using other name-mangling schemes. At least not yet; adding support is planned for 1.8.

Until then, one needs to use @JsonProperty annotation, or override internal classes (aside from AnnotationIntrospector there are other extension points that would work, but that's more of discussion for mailing lists).

Comment: Ok; Jackson 1.8 came with this new feature to do what was being asked: http://www.cowtowncoder.com/blog/archives/2011/03/entry_448.html (custom property naming strategies)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what "Pascal case" is but the answer is no. All Java object mappers have to comply to the [Java Beans API](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaBeans) which clearly defines the case for fields, setters and getters and how one name can be derived from another.

Comment: this is PascalCase, also known as UpperCamelCase